# Cross-thread signal slot, how to send char *

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I've created a simple Qt GUI App and I've created a simple thread in it using worker and worker thread (see below codes, it is a simple code which will be used in a large program).

In this program when I push the push button, the thread is created and started and then I send to the thread a `char *` containing a file name to be read. But when I send for example the string "salam", it shows me extra characters and file cannot be opened( in console):

```
"filename=salam▬»
ìax↔↑♂"
```

Why does this occur?

MainWindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(&workerThread,SIGNAL(finished()),
            worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connect(this, SIGNAL(operate(char *,int)),
            worker, SLOT(doWork(char *,int)));

    workerThread.start();
    char *name=new char[5];
    name[0]='s';name[1]='a';name[2]='l';name[3]='a';name[4]='m';
    emit operate(name,5);
    //vec=new QVector<double>();

}
```

worker.cpp:

```
void Worker::doWork(char *fileName,int size){
    cout<<"filename="<<fileName<<endl;
}
```

worker.h:

```
class Worker : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     QThread workerThread;
 public :
Worker();
 public slots:
     void doWork(char *fileName,int size) ;
 };

#endif // WORKER_H
```

(Don't forget to add CONFIG+= console in .pro file if you want to test it.)

Comment: First of all, why are you using char*?  This is C++ code with Qt, you should be using QString or std::string.  Second, the code is working as expected, but you don't need signals, slots, threads, or even a UI to demonstrate this behavior. See Stack Overflow's excellent page on [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MrEricSir  if I want to send QString or std::string then I must use typdef and qRegisterMetaType ... and it seems dirty code , so I used char * instead. also this is a part of a program which I've wrote it here and I know that fro this simple program I don't need such things!

Comment: @abdolah: MrEricSir's point about MCVE is important. About 80% of the code you posted is unnecessary to reproduce your problem. You should work on reducing your code to a minimal example before posting - makes your question easier to understand for everyone, including future visitors with the same type of issue.

Comment: First: You don't need to use `qRegisterMetaType` for Qt types, because they are already registered. Second: it is unsafe to pass pointer-to-arrays in such ways, because you will have a lot of potential problems with releasing memory..... AND: `qRegisterMetaType` - it's just 2 lines of code: what problems do you have there?!

Comment: @Mat , I think that maybe the problem is in somewhere in my code so I included all of my code in the question, anyway I corrected it and make it more minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is completely unrelated to Qt, signals or multiple threads.

The `char*` you're creating isn't null-terminated, so you cannot use it with functions (or operators) that expect `char*`s to be C strings - they rely on the null terminator. What you're seeing on your console is the result of that - the `operator<<` overload for `char*` will print out characters until a zero is encountered. You're printing whatever garbage values are stored in memory after your 5 characters (this is undefined behavior btw).

If you want to stick with `char*` for whatever reason, and expect to use it with functions that require C-style strings, you must zero-terminate it. (And take care of freeing it, that's not going to happen automatically.)